# Is there a resource where I could find myself a checker and critic, or check somebodies else text to exercise?

Tags: editing, resources, criticism

I need a checker and some kind of beta-test editor and critic. Is there a resource out in the web, where I can find myself one?

Comment: Vote to close; off-topic, [as per meta](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/66/should-we-allow-looking-for-editors-type-questions).

Comment: @neilfein: I disagree -- Daniel isn't asking for critiques, he's asking where one goes to find that sort of thing.  Identifying resources for writers is definitely on-topic.

Comment: @HedgeMage - You're correct. (I'd unvote to close if I could.)

Comment: @neilfein: I'm not sure, but I think you can cancel the close vote using the same link you did to cast it.

Comment: @HedgeMage - I tried that right off. Not the end of the world, the vote will expire in time.

Answer (score 4):

This list comprises well-known online critique and discussion groups that require varying levels of paticipation in exchange for feedback:: http://www.writing-world.com/links/critique.shtml.

Comment: Pedanticism pays off. (Only, there's no such word as pedanticism.)

Answer (score 3):

Try checking out

http://www.critiquecircle.com/

Not sure if it is good, sorry havn't used it (I'm waiting for the confirmation email now)

Comment: I would second the recommendation for Critique Circle. There are a lot of helpful resources there if you take the time to become familiar with the community.

Answer (score 2):

I've been a member of [Online Writing Workshop for Science Fiction, Fantasy, and Horror](http://sff.onlinewritingworkshop.com/) for a couple of years. I left because I didn't have enough time but the service was very good.

[How it works](http://sff.onlinewritingworkshop.com/howitworks.shtml).